# Sort relative paths

Tags: c++, qt

My problem is pretty simple, but i can't think of an elegant solution.
In my application a bunch of relative paths are collected from user input (they don't really exist in the filesystem).
As an example:

- somefile.ext
- z/file.ext
- A/B/file2.ext
- A/B/z/file.ext
- file1.ext
- A/B/file.ext

Those are gathered in a QList (which contains pointers to instances of a class that have the paths as a QString member), but the container doesn't really matter to me.
The desired result is having the list in an ordered form, directories over files (as we are used from most file managers), basically like you would tree a real filesystem.

- A/B/z/file.ext
- A/B/file.ext
- A/B/file2.ext
- z/file.ext
- file.ext
- somefile.ext

Obviously a normal string based sorting would not work, but what is the most elegant / easiest way to sort a list like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a custom [comparator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function for a builtin sort. Something like this may work:

```
auto cmp = [](const string& lhs, const string& rhs) {
    int len = min(lhs.size(), rhs.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (lhs[i] = rhs[i]) continue;

        // check if there is a '/' starting from position i in both paths
        // put directory first (if only one is a directory)
        // or return lhs[i] < rhs[i]
};
```

It should be fairly easy to finish this code,
and then

```
sort(begin(paths), end(paths), cmp);
```

Note that I'm using c++11

Comment: If i understand you correctly pseudo code would look like: `if (a.count('/') != b.count('/') return a.count('/') > b.count('/'); return a < b;`  But this would sort "X/X/X/file.ext" over "A/A/file.ext".

Comment: @ldr I assumed that you want "deeper" directories first (based on dirs vs files requirement), if you don't just change `if one has more '/'` into `if one has any '/' and the others doesn't than... `

Comment: I can't figure out what the `are_in_dirs` check should be good for. If you compare `somefile` with `x/somefile` your loop would end at the first char and `are_in_dirs` would stay false, therefore you would return `s < x`. The rest of the the comments sound right to me.

Comment: You're right, this check was unnecessary, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a step back, and take a moment to summarize your desired sorting criteria, in plain English:

1. Directories come first, files come second.
2. Directories are sorted alphabetically, and files are sorted alphabetically.

Now, once your logical is reduced to this kind of simplistic, straightforward definition, simply translate this logic directly into C++ code.

First, translate each string into a single value, 0 or 1, that represents whether the string has a pathname component, or not.

Sort on that. Then if both strings' values are equivalent, sort on the strings themselves, as usual. Simple:

```
std::sort(container.begin(),
          container.end(),
          []
          (const QString &a,
           const QString &b)
          {
             // Compute whether a or b is a subdirectory, representing
             // each as:
             //
             // 0: directory
             // 1: file

             int a_hier=a.contains('/') ? 0:1;
             int b_hier=b.contains('/') ? 0:1;

             if (a_hier != b_hier)
                  return a_hier < b_hier;

             return a < b;
         });
```

This is you basic, initial approach. If necessary, this can be tweaked to sort the pathnames with directories slightly differently (since the `/` component in the pathname participates in the relative sorting order, which you may or may not want, this was unclear in your question).

Comment: This would for example sort "A/B/z/file.ext" after "A/B/file.ext". I want it basically like a directory tree. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. But, you should be able to take my answer, and figure it out by yourself. It's only a few extra steps, beyond what is already outlined. Just spell out exactly how the additional comparison logic, here, should work, in plain English, using short, brief, logical sentences. Then [schedule an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Once your rubber duck agrees that your proposed algorithm will work, just translate it directly into C++ code. Mission accomplished.